# Как ограничить киберсквоттинг?

Tags: домен, логика

Если бы у вас была система доменов, в которой любой желающий мог бы занять любое незарегистрированное имя, как вы решили бы проблему занятия одним человеком большого пула свободных имен? Без участия модератора.

Количество доменов конечное. Но это очень большое число.

У вас есть маркер, позволяющий сессионно идентифицировать пользователя.
Пользователь может начать новую сессию и вы это не сможете отследить.

Введение лимитов на конкретный идентификатор не имеет смысла, потому что пользователь может сменить  его (идентификатор).

Comment: Регистрация по фото на которой видно лицо человека, его паспорт и монитор со страницей вашего сайта. И ни каких проблем.

Comment: @Visman но ведь написано - без участия модератора. Или вы предлагаете обучить нейронную сеть на распознование человека на картинке?) А по поводу вопроса. Если нет возможности идентифицировать пользователя, то никак. Разве что поставить ограничение на лимит регистраций в сутки)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, слона-то я и не приметил :)

Comment: Установить стоимость на регистрацию доменов такую, чтобы была не выгодная массовая регистрация доменов с целью перепродажи. Это полностью не решает вопрос, но как по мне, это понизит уровень киберсквоттинга.

Comment: Это вообще не решает проблему. Сейчас домены платные и на большинстве - самые сочные места заняты и перепродаются. Домены .tk бесплатны и там ситуация особо не меняется.

Comment: Попробуйте все же сменить название вопроса. Киберсквоттинг имеет ярковыраженную окраску и "историю". Как насчет такого названия вопроса - "Как решить проблему занятия одним человеком большого пула свободных имен?" и уточните, что именно в этом плохого в ВАШЕЙ системе.

Comment: Ну, название может быть действительно стоит изменить, но для чего мне описывать причину? Вполне самодостаточный вопрос. Есть проблема - требуется решение. Выкладываю суть проблемы на мозговой штурм сообщества. У людей может возникнуть аналогичный вопрос и не важно из-за чего, у кого-то доменами будут массивы имен, у других это могут быть url адреса +3 уровней, у третьих ещё что-то, но вопрос у них будет общий. Они выскажут своё мнение, может быть когда-нибудь решение найдется или я сам что-нибудь придумаю и опубликую решение.

Answer (score 0):

Никак бы не решал. Это невыгодно. Ведь система регистрации доменов получает деньги за регистрацию, значит чем больше регистраций - тем больше денег. Ограничивать количество регистраций - это как выкидывать деньги из кошелька в мусор.

Другое дело что какие-то домены могли быть зарегистрированы тем, кто на это не имеет права, а права определяются извне системы регистрации доменов. Торговые марки и тому подобные ограничения. В этом случае тоже не имеет смысла ограничивать регистрацию доменов. Выгодней будет следовать решениям суда о передаче доменов.

Comment: Значит удаляйте свой ответ. Потому что здесь вопрос в том "как", а не "зачем"

Comment: Отнюдь. [Вопрос "как?" не имеет смысла без вопроса "зачем?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)

Comment: С чего вы взяли что система продает домены? Об этом не было ни слова. Вопрос о том, как ограничить занятие чрезмерного количества доменных имен - одним человеком. Представьте что каждая регистрация лишь нагружает систему, например занимается место на диске, оно забивается записями о соответствии имени - правообладателю и никакой выгоды от этого не получает. И да, эта ссылка дважды неверна. Во первых мой вопрос о том, как решить X, а во вторых "Используйте ссылку на эту статью как дополнение к вашей аргументации, но не вместо нее"

Comment: Из каких слов в вашем вопросе я должен был сделать вывод что система *не продает* домены?

Comment: А с чего она должна их продавать? Я не говорил что продаю доменные имена, домен - обширное понятие. Хватит превращать этот вопрос в чат, не стоит больше писать сюда не по теме и обсуждать необходимость ограничения массовой регистрации